# Rephrasing of the "...mistake in Wikipedia..." questions

Tags: discussion

As of the previous meta question [Is this a mistake in the Wikipedia article for *? questions](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/152/127) we seem to agree on that such questions should be about the content and not the article itself.

Thus I'd like to rephrase at least the question titles and their respective first paragraph to match this and to prevent these questions from attracting more questions in this style. But I'm not sure how to phrase it.

Maybe the Radiosity question title could be changed to *Why do diffuse surfaces increase Radiosity calculations?*, but this does not hit the actual core of the question. For the other question I did not find a better title yet.

Or should we leave these two questions as they are? After all they already have answers. What do we do with these two questions?